# Is there a good way to store references to objects?

Tags: javascript

Coming from iOS, I'm used to having weak references between objects, so I can access data from wherever and not worry about reference cycles.

Not 100% sure on how Javascript works with something like this:

```
function One () {
    this.hello = 'hi from one';
    this.two = new Two(this);
}

function Two (one) {
    this.one = one;
}

Two.prototype.sayHi = function () {
    console.log(this.one.hello);
}

var o = new One();

o.two.sayHi(); // Outputs: hi from one
```

This *does* work, but is there a better way to do this? Should I be worried about memory here? Doing the same thing carelessly in iOS would get us into trouble.

Bonus: If this is actually safe, is there a way Javascript can leak memory? I know it's GC under the hood, but is there anything I should be watching out for that it might not catch?

Comment: Could you clarify where do you exactly see possible memory issues in that code?

Comment: Well I don't, because it's JS and it's handled via GC automatically, I just wanted to verify this is correct and there's no 'gotchas' to look out for, like there are in other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are afraid of here are cycles in reference graph. 
Garbage collectors can deal with cycles and are able to release objects which reference each other but does not have references to any of them from outside.

This is different to reference-counted memory management where cycles keep the memory and must be broken with weak references.

This does not, however, mean they you don't have to care about memory leaks as there are other ways to introduce them.